# How to display all results in linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I have a linq query that takes result from two tables.  But that query didn't display all results . When I test it in SQL Server, I have this :

```
| mcod  | pcod  | c_ogrn        | fam_v | im_v    | ot_v   | idGk
| 41004 | 10023 | 1027800518063 | Johny | Johnson | Andrew |  3   
| 41004 | 10023 | 1027800518063 | Johny | Johnson | Andrew | 11
```

You see that data in last column is different . But when I test in linq query i have this result:

```
| mcod  | pcod  | c_ogrn        | fam_v | im_v    | ot_v   | idGk
| 41004 | 10023 | 1027800518063 | Johny | Johnson | Andrew |   3   
| 41004 | 10023 | 1027800518063 | Johny | Johnson | Andrew |   3
```

Why queries is identical but results are different ?

My c# code :

```
 var fidn  = from post in repository.users
             join meta in repository.usersLG on post.pcod equals meta.pcod
             where post.fam_v.Trim() == "Johny" && post.actual == 1
             //where post.fa post.fam_v.Trim() == fambox.Text and post.actual=1
             select new Final
                          {
                              mcod = post.mcod,
                              pcod = post.pcod,
                              c_ogrn = post.c_ogrn,
                              fam_v = post.fam_v,
                              im_v = post.im_v,
                              ot_v = post.ot_v,
                              idGK = meta.idGK
                          };
```

My T-SQL query :

```
SELECT  
    users.[mcod], users.pcod, [c_ogrn], [fam_v], [im_v], [ot_v], idGk
FROM  
    [table].[dbo].[users]
JOIN
    [table].[dbo].[usersLG] ON users.pcod = usersLG.pcod 
WHERE 
    users.fam_v = 'Johny'
    AND users.actual = 1
```

Asp.net Web page, Entity Framework, C# linq, SQL Server

**UPDATE** my classes and primary keys:

users:

```
[Key]
public string pcod { get; set; }
public string mcod { get; set; } 
public string c_ogrn  { get; set; }
public string fam_v { get; set; } 
public string im_v { get; set; }
public string ot_v { get; set; }
public int actual { get; set; }
```

usersLG

```
[Key]
public string pcod { get; set; }
public int idGK { get; set; }
public string mcod { get; set; }
public byte actual { get; set; }
```

Final

```
[Key]
public int idGK { get; set; }
public string pcod { get; set; } 
public string mcod { get; set; }
public string c_ogrn { get; set; } 
public string fam_v { get; set; }
public string im_v { get; set; } 
public string ot_v { get; set; }
public int actual { get; set; }
```

Comment: What are the primary keys of `users` and `usersLG`?

Comment: @GertArnold users - pcod. usersLg - pcod . I need to make another primary key?

Comment: @asdnafn No- its only  in usersLg

Comment: Usually, repetitive data indicate a mismatch in unique identification in the database and EF. In other words, EF doesn't use the full primary key as it is defined in the database.

Comment: @GertArnold i added my classes and primary keys. what primary keys need to be set for right result?

Comment: The question is, are the primary key in the database the same as defined in EF (by the `[Key]` annotation)?

Comment: @ i didnt have primary keys in this tables in base

Comment: @АндрейГолубцов May be silly, but how did you visualize the data from your linq query? In debug mode with break point or printing on UI? If no error in looking at the data, your LINQ and SQL queries looks similar.

Comment: No PK in the database? Really? So how do you identify records from these tables unambiguously?

Comment: @GertArnold i have id columns. I didn't have permission to change database setting, because of that i need to change EF keys. Thank you for help  , after your answer i understand my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem , thanks Gert Arnold.
My problem was in same values in rows. Because i didn't define id columns - results was identical.
I just add id columns from table to my classes and add primary keys to them.
Now its all works!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the primary key in database should be same as the definition in entity framework definition.

Once the keys (primary,foreign) match it should work.